# Parse every line in a file and add them to array in shell script

Tags: shell

I have been working on developing a `init.d` script which will run when the machine stops and starts. The script runs along with the Tomcat server. The script will parse the configuration files of each tomcat instance and add them to a temporary file called "InstanceData". The contents will be some thing like this:

```
FINC-A1:XXXX979:XXXX   
FINC-B1:XXXX979:XXXX  
FXE-A1:XXXX975:XXXX  
FXE-B1:XXXX975:XXXX  
INL-A1:XXXX994:XXXX  
INL-B1:XXXX994:XXXX  
IVR-A1:XXXX984:XXXX  
IVR-B1:XXXX984:XXXX  
LWSP-A1:XXXX982:XXXX  
LWSP-B1:XXXX982:XXXX  
LWSP-C1:XXXX982:XXXX   
MFS-A1:XXXX989:XXXX   
MFS-I1:XXXX989:XXXX  
PHYRES-A1:XXXX987:XXXX  
PHYRES-B1:XXXX987:XXXX
```

Each line is a server with user ID and Machine seperated by colon. Now my script works fine when stop is executed. The problem is now I want the same servers of a domain needs to be started at same time. For example:

```
FINC-A1:XXXX979:XXXX   
FINC-B1:XXXX979:XXXX
```

Both belongs to `FINC` domain, now I want to write a script which will take same domains from the file and start them at same time. My problem was with extracting the instances that belong to the same domain like `FIND` or `IVR`. Please help me in writing the script. Thanks for all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ook , i was able to write the script which works fine to me

output=$(cat instanceData.txt  | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d'-' -f1 | uniq )

for x in $output;
  do
for ref_num in `cat instanceData.txt | grep $x`
  do
    echo "Performing action on $ref_num"
   done
done

Thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract from 'instanceData' file those instances that belong to domain e.g. `FINC` you can do the following:

If you want the whole line:

```
cat instanceData | awk '/FINC-.*/ { print $0 }'
```

Result:

```
FINC-A1:XXXX979:XXXX   
FINC-B1:XXXX979:XXXX
```

If you just want the first field:

```
cat instanceData | awk -F: '/FINC-.*/ { print $1 }'
```

Result:

```
 FINC-A1
 FINC-B1
```

Comment: Thanks for the Response , I was able to extract the details but what i need is a script implementation idea so that i can loop through the file and perform a action on all lines that has the same domain. In above case i need to run a command on all the FINC domain lines. more over that Instance data file can contain more number lines.